# Combining submodules, procedure arguments and polymorphic types

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, fortran2008

I am currently trying to split my code into modules and submodules. I have a number of procedures which take procedures as arguments, and in some cases the arguments of those procedure arguments are polymorphic. When splitting these procedures into submodules my code no longer compiles.

As a minimum working example, I have a module file `m.f90`:

```
module m
  implicit none
  
  ! Interface to `foo`, which simply calls `lambda(input)`.
  interface foo
    module subroutine foo(input,lambda)
      implicit none
      
      class(*), intent(in)  :: input
      procedure(TestLambda) :: lambda
    end subroutine
  end interface
  
  ! Interface to `bar`, which simply calls `lambda(input)`
  interface bar
    module subroutine bar(input,lambda)
      implicit none
      
      class(*), intent(in)  :: input
      procedure(TestLambda) :: lambda
    end subroutine
  end interface
  
  ! Interface defining the `lambda` arguments of `foo` and `bar`.
  interface TestLambda
    subroutine TestLambda(input)
      implicit none
      
      class(*), intent(in) :: input
    end subroutine
  end interface

end module
```

and a submodule file `m_sub.f90`:

```
submodule (m) m_sub
contains

  ! Implementation of `foo`.
  module subroutine foo(input,lambda)
    implicit none

    class(*), intent(in)  :: input
    procedure(TestLambda) :: lambda
    
    call lambda(input)
  end subroutine
  
  ! Implementation of `bar`.
  ! This is identical to `foo`, except that the interface is implicit.
  module procedure bar
    call lambda(input)
  end procedure

end submodule
```

and, for completeness, a program file `main.f90`:

```
program test
  use m
  implicit none
  
  write(*,*) 'Hello, World!'
  call test_lambda(1)
  call foo(1, test_lambda)
  call bar(1, test_lambda)
contains
  subroutine test_lambda(input)
    implicit none
    
    class(*), intent(in) :: input
    
    write(*,*) 'Hello, World!'
  end subroutine
end program
```

I am compiling this using CMake, with a `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
enable_language(Fortran)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mod/)

if("${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fcheck=all -std=f2008")
elseif("${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-stand f08 -warn all")
endif()

project(test)
add_executable(test main.f90 m.f90 m_sub.f90)
```

If I compile with `gfortran 10.1.0` then `foo` compiles and runs fine on its own, but trying to compile `bar` gives the error

```
   26 |       call lambda(input)
      |                  1
Error: Explicit interface required for polymorphic argument at (1)
```

If I instead compile with `ifort 2021.1` I get the compile-time warning (for both `foo` and `bar`)

```
 warning #8889: Explicit declaration of the EXTERNAL attribute is required.   [LAMBDA]
      call lambda(input)
-----------^
```

And then the linker error (for both `foo` and `bar`)

```
m_sub.f90.o: In function `m_mp_foo_':
undefined reference to `lambda_'
```

As far as I can tell, what I'm doing is valid Fortran. So am I seeing compiler bugs / unimplemented features? Or am I trying to do something which isn't allowed by the standard?